# Creating a monthly list with one row from mulitple records per customer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write code that will pull a list each month. The list pulls multiple records for each customer and I need the result set to return one row for each customer with a variety of aggregated information.

So when I run the following code I get the right answer for `Max` date giving me the last invoice for that customer and I get the right answer to sum amount adding up all the invoices still open. There will be other fields showing the aging on the account. But I’m getting as many rows per customer as I have invoices with each row showing the “right” answer to the two aggregated fields.

I started with looking up `Distinct` and can see that most answers come back with Windowing functions. I haven’t used them before and I’m getting confused on making them work. The output is required to be in a specific order which is why I have things listed the way I do. At this point I’ve read so many help forums I’m feeling punch drunk so I think I’m missing an obvious answer.

```
SELECT  cl.[document type] AS [RecordType], 
        c.[no_], 
        c.[name], 
        c.[name 2], 
        c.[address], 
        c.[address 2], 
        c.city, 
        c.[post code] AS [Zip], 
        c.[county] AS [State], 
        c.[country_region code] AS CountyTrim, 
        Month(Getdate()) AS [FigMonth], 
        Day(Getdate()) AS [FigDay], 
        Year(Getdate()) AS [FigYear], 
        --Next 2 lines should pull last invoice for customer to fill LastSaleDate field 
        (
        SELECT Max(cl2.[posting date]) 
        FROM [dbo].[detailed cust_ ledg_ entry] AS cl2 
        WHERE  cl2.[document type] = 2 AND cl2.[customer no_] = c.[no_]
        ) AS [LastSaleDate], 
        c.[payment terms code] AS [Terms 1], 
        --iif instead of case to fill Terms1Open field 
        Iif (c.[payment terms code] = 'CreditCard/Pre-Auth', 'N', 'Y') AS [Terms1Open], 
        --Now totaling invoices per customer 
        (
        SELECT Sum(cl3.[amount]) 
        FROM [dbo].[detailed cust_ ledg_ entry] AS cl3 
        WHERE cl3.[customer no_] = c.[no_] 
        GROUP BY cl3.[customer no_]
        ) AS [DollarsTotal] 
FROM   [dbo].[customer] AS c 
JOIN [dbo].[detailed cust_ ledg_ entry] AS cl 
    ON c.[no_] = cl.[customer no_] 
JOIN [dbo].[cust_ ledger entry] AS l 
    ON l.[document no_] = cl.[document no_] 
WHERE   l.[open] = 1 
        AND cl.[document type] = 2 
        AND c.[customer posting group] IN ( 'BIKECUST', 'OUTDRCUST' ) 
ORDER  BY c.[no_]
```

Comment: That formatting make me want to take out my eyeballs and shoot them with a sandblaster. Sometime the alias is on the same line, other times it isn't. Spending 10 minutes to clean up your sql would be step one. Step 2 is getting help from an online forum. For this process you should start here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Ouch! Hear what you have said. Will try to do better. Found lots of answers here so it was one of the first places I turned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what it is you're trying to do, but based on your SQL, I've rewritten it to do what I think the code best described as logical.

If I may offer a suggestion, if this is  your own schema - I'd seriously think about renaming literally *everything* to conform to best practices.

```
SELECT   CL.[document type] AS [RecordType]
        ,C.[no_]
        ,C.[name]
        ,C.[name 2]
        ,C.[address] 
        ,C.[address 2] 
        ,C.city 
        ,C.[post code] AS [Zip]
        ,C.[county] AS [State] 
        ,C.[country_region code] AS CountyTrim
        ,Month(Getdate()) AS [FigMonth] 
        ,Day(Getdate()) AS [FigDay] 
        ,Year(Getdate()) AS [FigYear] 
        ,MAX(CL.[posting date]) AS [LastSaleDate]
        ,C.[payment terms code] AS [Terms 1]
        ,CASE  WHEN C.[payment terms code] = 'CreditCard/Pre-Auth' 
               THEN 'N' 
               ELSE 'Y' END AS [Terms1Open]
        ,SUM(CL.[amount]) AS [DollarsTotal] 
  FROM   dbo.Customer C
  JOIN   dbo.[detailed cust_ ledg_ entry] CL
    ON   C.[no_] = CL.[customer no_]
  JOIN   dbo.[cust_ ledger entry]  L 
    ON   L.[document no_] = CL.[document no_]
 WHERE   L.[open] = 1 
   AND   CL.[document type] = 2 
   AND   C.[customer posting group] IN ( 'BIKECUST', 'OUTDRCUST' ) 
 GROUP
    BY   CL.[document type]
        ,C.[no_]
        ,C.[name]
        ,C.[name 2]
        ,C.[address] 
        ,C.[address 2] 
        ,C.city 
        ,C.[post code]
        ,C.[county]   
        ,C.[country_region code]
        ,Month(Getdate())                                              
        ,Day(Getdate())                                                
        ,Year(Getdate())     
        ,CASE  WHEN C.[payment terms code] = 'CreditCard/Pre-Auth' 
               THEN 'N' 
               ELSE 'Y' END
  ORDER  
     BY  C.[no_]
```

Comment: Thank you. Not my schema and my problem obviously was more about my work than the schema I have to work with. This answer will allow me to move forward with the rest. I'll try to do better when wording my requests.

Comment: I'm just glad that I was able to read the logic well enough to get the ball rolling for you!